# Need to create an Android In-App purchase, that expires in 2 months. What are the options?

Tags: android, security, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Of course I'm aware about the possibility of [consuming a purchase](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Consume), so I can get the purchase time, add 2 months to it, and compare the result with the current date. But this way is pretty complex: 1) we have to check the expiration from time to time; 2) we should create a protection from setting a wrong system date/time.

So I'm wondering if there are other ways to implement it.

*By the way, it would be great if somebody shared his/her experience in creating a protection from setting a wrong system date/time.*

Answer (score 0):

Don't use device setting, use your app server time: on purchase, save time on server. Now, each request to server can check the time (on the server) and validate the purchase hasn't expired.

EDIT: If you don't use app server and require to implement it locally, you can use an api to a site that provide a timestamp. I believe it's less secure, because now an attacker just need to reverse engineer your app. In the first solution (assuming you implement it securely), an attacker will have to reverse engineer both your app and your server implementation)

Comment: The question is, how does the server know the user has really purchased the item?  We also don't know if this app already has a server component or not.

Comment: The server knows because the app update the server on the purchase time (so server has a map between user identity and its expiration time). Now each time app connect to server, the server can validate the user. If the app don't contains any server component, how can you decide if current device belong to a paid user? How purchasing is done without a server component?

Comment: What would keep an attacker from submitting a request to the server without making a purchase? And you don't need a server to do in app purchases.

Comment: Nothing would, the server job is to get the identity from the app and validate it (the identity can be generated using google play api, for example). About the server existence, you're right, you don't have to use app server to use in app purchase - you can use only google play server. I will edit my answer to handle such a case.

Comment: Are you talking about this for validation? http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html  Looks like a good plan, it just requires the user to pick a google account to use with the app.